# Why grep shows different results when I use file1 as a pattern on file2 and viceversa?

Tags: command-line, files, grep

When I run `grep -m 1 -Fnxvf file1 file2`, for some couple of files I get a different line number than running `grep -m 1 -Fnxvf file2 file1` (*swapped files*).

Why?

---

I've reduced the files to a minimal example.

file1

```
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 132, y = 1432 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 136, y = 1432 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 84, y = 1436 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 88, y = 1436 }
```

file2

```
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 132, y = 1432 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 84, y = 1436 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 88, y = 1436 }
Pp: 1        Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 92, y = 1436 }
```

Results I get:

```
$ grep -m 1 -Fnaxvf file2 file1
2:Pp: 1      Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 136, y = 1432 }
$ grep -m 1 -Fnaxvf file1 file2
4:Pp: 1      Id pezzo 193        posIn = { x = 92, y = 1436 }
```

The first result is exactly what I'm expecting, but in the second case I expected to see (and usually it is so), the second line of `file2`.

---

**Long explanation**

I'm trying to find (and show) the first difference between two files. I want to show **only** the first difference, and the line where it happens.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079109/2508150) answer on SO (have a look at my comment to the answer) and it seems to work, but for some couple of files I've noticed the strange behavior showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: you have no guarantee grep will use your pattern in order.

Suppose you have two files with following contents (one letter per line, I fold for readability)

> File 1

```
A B D E
```

and

> File 2

```
A B C D
```

- The first excluded (since you use -v ) letter from set 2 (A B C D ) in file 1 is E.
- The first excluded letter from set 1 in file 2 is C.

Comparison of files is usually:

- `cmp file1 file2` for binary file, when you don't care about diff (you can even use cmp -s (silent))
- `diff file1 file2` which show a pseudo sed code to go from file1 to file2 (diff file2 file1 is quite symmetric)
- `comm -123 file1 file2` to show lines in common (-3) in file1 (-1) in file2 (-2)

Comment: Do you know a way I can use `cmp`, `diff` or `comm` to show **only** the first difference and its line number?

Comment: output can be limited to X first lines using `| head -X`

Comment: `diff` can be convinced to show line numbers: `diff --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format="" --new-line-format="%dn:%L" oldfile newfile | head -1` ought to show the first such line (as it appears in newfile; swap formats for vice-versa) with line number.  And now I'm wondering how to combine this with `diff -y`-like output …